# Bigcommerce v3 API throwing error " value is already used on this option"

Tags: api, bigcommerce

I want to create a product with its variants using Bigcommerce v3 API. The json which I am passing as parameter is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "Western Blotting Boxes",
  "type": "physical",
  "price": "16.0",
  "description": "7.3 x 3 x 1.9cm",
  "weight": 0,
  "width": 7,
  "height": 4,
  "depth": 4,
  "page_title": "",
  "meta_keywords": [],
  "meta_description": "",
  "fixed_cost_shipping_price": 0,
  "inventory_tracking": "variant",
  "inventory_level": 100,
  "brand_id": 38,
  "categories": [
    25,
    24
  ],
  "variants": [
    {
      "cost_price": "28.2",
      "price": "47.0",
      "sku": "B1200-15",
      "inventory_level": 1000000000,
      "option_values": [
        {
          "option_display_name": "Size",
          "label": "4 9/16 x 4 9/16 x 1 1/4in. "
        },
        {
          "option_display_name": "Box Color",
          "label": "Clear"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cost_price": "30.0",
      "price": "50.0",
      "sku": "B1200-15BK",
      "inventory_level": 1000000000,
      "option_values": [
        {
          "option_display_name": "Size",
          "label": "4 9/16 x 4 9/16 x 1 1/4in."
        },
        {
          "option_display_name": "Box Color",
          "label": "Opaque Black"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When I am sending a request to create product I am getting and error

The option label: "4 9/16 x 4 9/16 x 1 1/4in. value is already used on this option.

How I can handle this error ?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the extra space between the period and the double quotes in the first instance of `"label": "4 9/16 x 4 9/16 x 1 1/4in. "`

When I tested, removing the space allowed the request to go through.

Response to this question also posted in the BigCommerce Community:
https://forum.bigcommerce.com/s/feed/0D51B000048NMlOSAW?t=1517344095731

Comment: In my case was that some labels were downcased and other were upcased.